# Javascript for disabling buttons not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, button, internet-explorer-9

so I'm writing an interface for updating and displaying a database table, and each row displayed on the client-side (using DataTables) has an "Edit" and "Delete" button. Every time you click on a single row's Edit, all the Edit and Delete buttons in other rows are disabled. This is the Javascript code I use to do it:

```js
        var editButtons = document.getElementsByName("EditRow");
        var deleteButtons = document.getElementsByName("DeleteRow");

        for (i in editButtons) {
            editButtons[i].disabled = true;
        }

        for (i in deleteButtons) {
            deleteButtons[i].disabled = true;
        }
```

This works fine with Chrome and Firefox, but when I try it in IE9, it doesn't disable anything. I've tried many things to solve this, including grabbing the DOM objects using jQuery, but nothing has worked. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName` returns a [**node list**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList), which is Array-like. You should treat it as such:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('something'),
    len = elements.length; 
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: This worked as well as Joseph Silber's solution. Thank you! So the syntax for(x in array) wont work for arrays?

Comment: @Mike_Perry, it will return properties as well not just indexes. So avoid using for...in with arrays or you will get weird results.

Comment: Installed IE9 and tested it. Works like a charm. Test it at: http://jsfiddle.net/FKLze/1/

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory, I see. When I iterated through it, I did get a bunch of properties, the collection of Html inputs being the first element. I wonder why this works for Chrome, though?

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't work in IE9, but this does:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByName('EditRow'), function(el){
    el.disabled = true;
});
```

Comment: This actually worked beautifully. That is all sorts of crazy, never seen that before. Thank you!

Comment: @Mike_Perry Please consider trying the other solution aswell. I **really** dislike changing the general behaviour of arrays on foreach loops! Bad practice in my opinion!

Comment: @Smamatti, I have decided to go with the other solution. Thank you for the advice. FYI it works for Chrome and Firefox as well :)

Comment: @Smamatti - Please help me out of my ignorance: What's wrong with using the prototype? Would you rather I use `[].forEach`? I like the simplicity of `forEach`!